# Fetching data from server in Container and passing it to Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I've been learning React for the past few weeks and I'm struggling with a way to fetch a collection of data from server and presenting it using Redux.

**What I have:**

I have a `<MoviesList />` component which renders a list of `<Movie />` components inside it.

**What i need:**

I need to fetch these movies from a server and store it in my state.

**What I'm struggling with:**

If I create a container component, I'll use mapStateToProps to pass the movies from the state down to my `<MoviesList />` component, but first I need to fetch it from the server, so I thought that I should do it in one of the container component's lifecycle hook, but then I'll have a `movies` prop (which should be validated with PropTypes) both in my `<MoviesListContainer />` and `<MoviesList />`, which will force me to write a big prop validation in both components, which doesn't look right at all for me.

This wouldn't be a problem if I were to simply spread the props in the container using a function component, but since I need to fetch the movies in the lifecycle hook, it needs to be a class and I need to specify the props in both files.

So what would be the best way to achieve this?

Should I fetch these movies in a different place? Should I take a different approach for fetching it and avoiding these duplications? Or maybe I really should do the validation in both files?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in the past is to have a function property which is called in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle event:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onMount();
}
```

That property is mapped in the container using `mapDispatchToProps` to a thunk or some other async action (see [the Async Actions documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html)).

For a more sophisticated alternative see [Redux First Router](https://github.com/faceyspacey/redux-first-router) which allows to dispatch async actions from the router.

Answer (score 0):

@JCE is right, you need to look into [Async Actions](https://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html). If you want to fetch the data and store it in Redux before passing it to your component, you must use a side-effect library (redux-thunks, redux-sagas, etc). The reason is that Redux actions are synchronous by nature and fetching an API is an asynchronous operation. The side-effects libraries will help you achieve that.